# linear gradient underline for hyperlink

Tags: css

I would like to apply a linear gradient to my links. The code below works fine as long as the hyperlink's text stays on the same line. However when the text is splitted into several lines (ie: because the browser width is small), only the last line of the hyperlink has an underline.

Does anyone know how I could fix it? Or if I'm using the right approach to achieve this?

```
a{
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   border-bottom: none;
   position: relative;
}


a::after {
   content:'';
   width:100%;
   position: absolute;
   left:0;
   bottom:-1px;
   height: 3px;
   background: #30e8bf;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #30e8bf, #ff8235);
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #30e8bf, #ff8235);
}
```

[You can test it on this CodePen sketch](https://codepen.io/mchrbn/pen/XROgbw)

Comment: underline is a gradient already

Comment: @chiragsolanki I don't think you read the question.

Comment: I won't take credit for it, I found it here http://codepen.io/poopsplat/pen/MaedPx but this seems to work https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/ZKwyrg

Comment: @dm please check it https://codepen.io/palimadra/pen/fFBDz

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichaelCoker !

Comment: @drnn you bet :)

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way would be to use background-image. This will require some adjustments but it should get you started:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWaRKW)

```
a {
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),linear-gradient(to right, #30e8bf, #ff8235);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 120%, 122%, 0 130%;
background-size: 100% 10px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.headline{
border-width: 3px;
width: 20%;
height: 4px;
margin: 0px auto;
text-decoration: underline;
background: linear-gradient(to right, #2AD7BD , #2AD7E8);}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="headline"></div>
```